# Drawing a line down the centre mean of the density plots for EACH facet

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

Aim: I would like to draw a line down the mean for EACH individual facet.

I currently have plotted a line for the mean of all facets:

```
ggplot(mexi_sf, aes(FOODEXP)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.1,fill="red",colour="red") +
 facet_wrap(~ADM1NAME)+xlim(0, 436)+ geom_vline(xintercept=227)+
ggsave("myplot.png")
```

Note: I know 227 is the mean from the `summary` function.

[image]

[Here's the data](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/13vOV-gRdvTLQ14y9wnzw3tdgCm1jxiWE) that can be imported with:

```
mexi_sf<-read_sf( dsn = getwd()
           , layer = "MexicoCaseStudy"
           , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that by grouping the data by administration. Note that you have missing values coded as `-9999` in your data. Recode them first, then use `na.rm` when compting the means per group.

```
mexi_sf %>%
  select(ADM1NAME, FOODEXP) %>%
  mutate(FOODEXP = ifelse(FOODEXP == -9999, NA, FOODEXP)) %>%
  group_by(ADM1NAME) %>%
  mutate(MEANEXP = mean(FOODEXP, na.rm = T)) -> mexi_sf


ggplot(mexi_sf, aes(FOODEXP)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.1,fill="red",colour="red") +
  facet_wrap(~ADM1NAME) + xlim(0, 436) + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=MEANEXP))+
  ggsave("myplot.png")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Martin, you seem to know a lot about facets, I have a new question about titles if you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49549472/set-specific-title-for-each-facet-in-r

Comment: The exact answer I was searching for. Thanks!